# add a menu in the drupal 7 system as a sub menu of the main menu

Tags: menu, drupal-7

How can I add a menu in the drupal system as a sub menu of the main menu?

I have an organic group which has a menu and I want to display this menu as sub menu in the primary links
so when I edit the menu I edit the og menu and the changes will display as a sub menu in the primary links.

how can I do that??
Please any advice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit your OG menu links and set them as children of the Primary menu (Main Menu if Drupal 7).

So you are just changing the logic of

"making the OG menu a child of Main Menu"

to:

"making the OG menu *links* children of Main Menu"